# Combination of logic operators in an equation in JavaScript, can someone explain it to me?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain how would this equation work? There're too many operators combined in this equation.

```
url = tmpUrl && tmpUrl.indexOf("/customURL?") > -1 ? tmpUrl.substring(0, tmpUrl.indexOf("/customURL")) : tmpUrl.split("?")[0] || tmpUrl
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see any bitwise operators here?

Comment: Bitwise operators use just a single character `&` or `|`. The doubled `&&` and `||` are [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and they are very different from the bitwise versions.

Comment: Its saying, if there is a `tmpUrl` and `&&` /customURL? exists `tmpUrl.indexOf("/customURL?") > -1` then grab the url and path otherwise spilt on the `?` and get the url params but this is a very verbose what of `decodeURIComponent(uri)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it just translates down to this

```
if (tmpUrl) {
  if (tmpUrl.indexOf("/customURL?") > -1) {
    url = tmpUrl.substring(0, tmpUrl.indexOf("/customURL"))
  } else {
    if (tmpUrl.split("?")[0]){
      url = tmpUrl.split("?")[0]
    } else {
      url = tmpUrl
    }
  }
}
```

And there are no bitwise operators used here